# How to see the actual HttpPost request being sent

Tags: android, http, http-post

There are bugs in my code and I can't figure out where it's happening exactly.

My code looks roughly like this...

```
        data.add(firstName);
        data.add(lastName);
        data.add(email);
        data.add(country);
        data.add(currency);
        data.add(phone);

        String result; // results of Http execution
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

The request is not getting the response I expect (i.e. the one I get when I use cUrl.

I'd like to see the exact request that `httpClient` is making. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what exactly you want to see like params or request url etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print all request details as follows:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
    post.getAllHeaders();
    post.getMethod(); // Post or get request 
    post.getParams(); // Returns params
    post.getURI(); // Current Uri called
```

Once you get response,

```
    response.getAllHeaders();
    httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); // response status
```